# in Bootstrap, how to keep "same" padding in big and small screen?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

For example, I want `p` to have `200px` padding on the left and right. It looks fine on a big screen, but on mobile it has too much padding. How can I solve this problem?

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 mystyle">
    <p> here is text </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mystyle p { 
  padding: 0 200px; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about media queries here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

```css
.mystyle p {
  padding: 0 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mystyle p {
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 mystyle">
    <p> here is text </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use percentage instead best will be writing media query

i personally use rem as unit instead of px  (My personal choice)

in media query it works as you specify the width of device either max width or min width ie

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
            .visible-xs {
                display: inline-block !important;
            }

            .block {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100%;
                height: 1px !important;
            }
        }
```